# Populate a ComboBox based on a chain of selection criteria

Tags: excel, combobox, excel-formula, vba

I have two worksheets, let's call them worksheetA and worksheetZ:

**WorksheetA** has two columns that we're interested in - "Order"(Col C) and "Customer" (Col D).
The "Customer" column holds a combo box/drop down list populated by a load of customers' names.
The "Order" column holds another combo box/drop down list with details about the order from this customer, such as order number, customer code, and order description.
(I understand this is a bad layout by the way, it's not my design). Example:

```
value in Customer Column (column D): "Google"  
value in Order Column (column C): "1234 - GOO - An order from google."
```

**WorksheetZ** contains two columns that interest us, it holds the values that are used to populate the ComboBoxes in WorksheetA:

again, an "Order" column (Column A), which contains the same data, but the data is split into rows, instead of being a drop down list, and the "Order" drop down list in worksheetA is currently populated by all of the rows in this column.

And a "Customer" column again, which holds customer names - "Google" - "IBM" etc.

Currently, the "Order" column in WorksheetA is populated using this data validation `=WorksheetZ!$A:$A` which will select ALL orders (over 300 at the moment!)

I need to be able to display ONLY orders for customers that are already selected in WorksheetA.Customer in the "Order" dropdown on worksheet A.

So, (and please forgive my terrible SQL-like-pseudo-code)

**WorksheetA.Order = (Select * from WorksheetZ.Order where worksheetA.Customer = WorksheetZ.Customer)**

[Here's the drop-down for WorksheetA.Customer (I've removed company-sensitive info)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOyqV.png)

[Here is WorksheetZ (again censored), where "Column1" in "A" is "Orders", and "Client" is "Customers"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8wCm.png)

Comment: Can you clarify..if you select Google in A3 then for B3 you want only options for Google orders? You should have one column for looking up the company name (a list of companies) but you will need two columns for the order (one with the company that ordered it, and another with the order number/detail itself). Is your data set up this way?

Comment: WorksheetZ contains a link between each order and the customer name.

Comment: I've amended my original post with some pictures, I hope they explain it better.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would handle it. I created a workbook with two sheets one called "Lookups" and another called "Validation". You'll have to adjust this to fit your situation. Create the following..

**Named Ranges** *(entire columns in Lookups worksheet)*:

*Company (The static list of companies)

CompanyLookup (The column that links company to order)

OrderLookup (The column with the list of orders)

MatchOrder (A blank column to build a list of matched orders)*

**Cell Validation** *(in Validation worksheet)*:

*For Company - List -->"=Company"

For Order - List -->"=MatchOrder"*

**VBA Code Behind**

In the VBA editor, add this code to the "Validation" worksheet

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    UpdateValidationList Target
End Sub
```

Then add this code to a new module

```
Dim CompanyCol As Long
Dim OrderCol As Long
Dim MatchCol As Long
Dim WriteRow As Long
Dim RowCounter As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet

Sub UpdateValidationList(rng As Range)
    Set ws = Sheets("Lookups")
    WriteRow = 1
    Range("MatchOrder").Clear
    CompanyCol = Range("CompanyLookup").Column
    OrderCol = Range("OrderLookup").Column
    MatchCol = Range("MatchOrder").Column
    LastRow = ws.Cells(100000, CompanyCol).End(xlUp).Row
    For RowCounter = 1 To LastRow
        If ws.Cells(RowCounter, CompanyCol) = rng.Value Then
            ws.Cells(WriteRow, MatchCol) = ws.Cells(RowCounter, OrderCol)
            WriteRow = WriteRow + 1
        End If
    Next RowCounter
End Sub
```

This will create a validation list of only matching orders in the range "MatchOrder" which is where your validation is looking. This is invisible to the user. TODO: Error handling

*As an aside, these sorts of tasks are a great deal easier to handle with an Access database. Consider migrating this functionality*

Comment: I'll try this soon and let you know - thanks for the answer and the effort you put into it! If it works for me then I'll mark is as correct, but that looks good :)